# V9 Primavera - C# erro no atributo "Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo"

Tags: c#

Boa tarde a todos,

E desde já obrigado pela atenção,

Criei um código em C# para fazer transformação de documentos.

Estou a ter um erro:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
>   HResult=0x80131500   Message='object' does not contain a definition
>   for 'DaValorAtributo'   Source= 
>   StackTrace:

Em VBA este código funciona perfeitamente, que já o fiz antes com sucesso.

Marquei com linha "----------" e comentário a linha que me está a dar o erro.

...C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Interop.ErpBS900;
using Interop.StdPlatBS900;
using Interop.StdBE900;
using Interop.GcpBE900;
using Interop.IGcpBS900;

namespace Docs_Trans
{
    class Program
    {

        public static StdPlatBS Platform { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Returns the engine that allows acess to the modules.
        /// </summary>
        public static ErpBS Engine { get; set; }



       public static void InitializeCompany()
        {

            StdBSConfApl objAplConf = new StdBSConfApl();
            StdPlatBS Plataforma = new StdPlatBS();
            ErpBS MotorLE = new ErpBS();

            EnumTipoPlataforma objTipoPlataforma = new EnumTipoPlataforma();
            objTipoPlataforma = EnumTipoPlataforma.tpEmpresarial;

            objAplConf.Instancia = "Default";
            objAplConf.AbvtApl = "ERP";
            objAplConf.PwdUtilizador = "pass";
            objAplConf.Utilizador = "user";
            objAplConf.LicVersaoMinima = "9.00";

            StdBETransaccao objStdTransac = new StdBETransaccao();

            Plataforma.AbrePlataformaEmpresa("empres", ref objStdTransac, ref objAplConf, ref objTipoPlataforma, "");


            if (Plataforma.Inicializada)
            {

                Platform = Plataforma;

                bool blnModoPrimario = true;

                MotorLE.AbreEmpresaTrabalho(EnumTipoPlataforma.tpEmpresarial, "empresa", "user", "pass", ref objStdTransac, "Default", ref blnModoPrimario);
                MotorLE.set_CacheActiva(true);

                Engine = MotorLE;

                ////MOTORES DE CRIAR E TRANSFORMAR DOCUmento
                ///


                ////Query de pesquisa de documentos e colocação em lista para fazer o ciclo

                StdBELista ListaDocsAtransformar = new StdBELista();

                ListaDocsAtransformar = Engine.Consulta("select TipoDoc, Serie, NumDoc from CabecDoc where tipodoc in (select CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUIORIG from tdu_pnt_docsequivalencia) and serie in (select CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUIORIG from tdu_pnt_docsequivalencia) and CDU_PNT_TRANSFORMADO <> 1");


                while (!ListaDocsAtransformar.NoFim())
                {



                    GcpBEDocumentoVenda DocVendaTransformado = new GcpBEDocumentoVenda();


                    object DocumentosOrigem;


                    /// DocumentosOrigem = Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo( "000", "ECN", "serie", "numdoc", "ID"));


///----------
//// aqui tenho o erro a indicar que davaloratributo, não existe no object???
///----------


                    object IDDoc = Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID");





                    DocumentosOrigem = Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(IDDoc.ToString());


                    string[] DocumentosOrigemArray = (string[])DocumentosOrigem;

                    object DocInicial;

                    DocInicial = Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_TipoEntidade();


                    ////Vai verificar qual o documento e serie correspondente 
                    ///

                    StdBELista ListaTipoDocSerie = new StdBELista();

                    ListaTipoDocSerie = Engine.Consulta("select CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUITRANS, CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUITRANS from tdu_pnt_DOCSEQUIVALENCIA where CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUIORIG = 'gr' and CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUIORIG = '2019'");


                    DocVendaTransformado.set_Serie(ListaTipoDocSerie.Valor("CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUITRANS").ToString());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_DataDoc(DateTime.Today);
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_TipoEntidade(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_TipoEntidade());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_TipoEntidadeFac(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_TipoEntidadeFac());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_Entidade(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_Entidade());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_EntidadeFac(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_EntidadeFac());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_Filial(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_Filial());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_Moeda(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_Moeda());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_Cambio(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_Cambio());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_CambioMAlt(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_CambioMAlt());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_CambioMBase(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_CambioMBase());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_Tipodoc(ListaTipoDocSerie.Valor("CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUITRANS").ToString());
                    DocVendaTransformado.set_CondPag(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(Engine.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("tipodoc").ToString(), ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("serie").ToString(), Int32.Parse(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("numdoc").ToString()), "ID").ToString()).get_CondPag());


                    Engine.Comercial.Vendas.TransformaDocumentoEX2(DocumentosOrigemArray, DocVendaTransformado, true, "", false);

                    //cria historico
                    Platform.ExecSql.ExecutaXML("");
                    //update que foi transformado na CDU_PNT_TRANSFORMADO do cabecdoc
                    Platform.ExecSql.ExecutaXML("");


                    ListaDocsAtransformar.Seguinte();

                }

            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            InitializeCompany();

        }



    }

}
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boas, tens aí coisas que não me parecem as mais correctas, como seja, fazeres uma consulta dos documentos e não puxares logo o Id, em vez do tipodoc, serie e numdoc. Outra coisa que estás a fazer é a editar varias vezes o documento para ires buscar a informação. Basta editares uma vez. Coloco aqui o exemplo:

```
        if (Plataforma.Inicializada)
        {

            Platform = Plataforma;

            bool blnModoPrimario = true;

            MotorLE.AbreEmpresaTrabalho(EnumTipoPlataforma.tpEmpresarial, "empresa", "user", "pass", ref objStdTransac, "Default", ref blnModoPrimario);
            MotorLE.set_CacheActiva(true);

            Engine = MotorLE;

            StdBELista ListaDocsAtransformar = new StdBELista();

            //Alterei aqui, indo buscar o Id, em vez dos outros campos
            ListaDocsAtransformar = Engine.Consulta("select Id from CabecDoc where tipodoc in (select CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUIORIG from tdu_pnt_docsequivalencia) and serie in (select CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUIORIG from tdu_pnt_docsequivalencia) and CDU_PNT_TRANSFORMADO <> 1");


            while (!ListaDocsAtransformar.NoFim())
            {

                GcpBEDocumentoVenda DocVendaTransformado = new GcpBEDocumentoVenda();

                //Alterei aqui. Editar o documento com o ID
                GcpBEDocumentoVenda DocumentosOrigem = Engine.Comercial.Vendas.EditaID(ListaDocsAtransformar.Valor("Id").ToString());

                object[] DocumentosOrigemArray = new object[] { DocumentosOrigem };

                StdBELista ListaTipoDocSerie = Engine.Consulta("select CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUITRANS, CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUITRANS from tdu_pnt_DOCSEQUIVALENCIA where CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUIORIG = 'gr' and CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUIORIG = '2019'");

                DocVendaTransformado.set_Serie(ListaTipoDocSerie.Valor("CDU_PNT_SERIEEQUITRANS").ToString());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_DataDoc(DateTime.Today);
                DocVendaTransformado.set_TipoEntidade(DocumentosOrigem.get_TipoEntidade());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_TipoEntidadeFac(DocumentosOrigem.get_TipoEntidadeFac());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_Entidade(DocumentosOrigem.get_Entidade());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_EntidadeFac(DocumentosOrigem.get_EntidadeFac());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_Filial(DocumentosOrigem.get_Filial());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_Moeda(DocumentosOrigem.get_Moeda());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_Cambio(DocumentosOrigem.get_Cambio());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_CambioMAlt(DocumentosOrigem.get_CambioMAlt());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_CambioMBase(DocumentosOrigem.get_CambioMBase());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_Tipodoc(ListaTipoDocSerie.Valor("CDU_PNT_TIPODOCEQUITRANS").ToString());
                DocVendaTransformado.set_CondPag(DocumentosOrigem.get_CondPag());


                Engine.Comercial.Vendas.TransformaDocumentoEX2(DocumentosOrigemArray, DocVendaTransformado, true, "", false);

                //cria historico
                Platform.ExecSql.ExecutaXML("");
                //update que foi transformado na CDU_PNT_TRANSFORMADO do cabecdoc
                Platform.ExecSql.ExecutaXML("");


                ListaDocsAtransformar.Seguinte();

            }
```

Comment: Bom dia,
Resolveu a questão do davalorAtributo está resolvida.

Obrigado

Esta conversão de objecto para Array é que me dá o erro de: 
"Unable to cast COM object of type 'Interop.GCPBE900.GcpBEDocumentoVendaClass' to class type System.String[]"

"string[] DocumentosOrigemArray = (string[])((object)DocumentosOrigem);"

Que também é um questão que me estou a debater.

Se for preferível crio outra questão.

Comment: Editei o código e já coloquei o correcto ( object[] DocumentosOrigemArray = new object[] { DocumentosOrigem }; ). Na verdade o array deve ser de objectos e não se strings, como estavas a colocar. Caso te resolveu o problema, marca a resposta como válida ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, experiementa alterares o código para algo parecido com este:

```
StdBELista lista = PriEngine.BSO.Consulta("Select tipodoc, serie, numdoc from cabecdoc where id = 'F1772FAA-EBD8-11DD-8838-000C2989A062'");
string tipodoc = lista.Valor("tipodoc").ToString();
string serie = lista.Valor("serie").ToString();
int numdoc = Convert.ToInt32(lista.Valor("numdoc"));
dynamic IDDoc = PriEngine.BSO.Comercial.Vendas.DaValorAtributo("000", tipodoc, serie, numdoc, "ID");
```

Comment: Sim essa foi uma das soluções que apliquei, mas prefiro sempre utilizar os motores Primavera sempre que possivel.

Comment: Esta solução usa os motores de igual forma, mas o problema tem a ver com o facto do método ter os parâmetros por referência.